# How to implement sub category elements in Property Grid using C#

Tags: c#, propertygrid

Is there any way to implement `sub category` elements in the `Property Grid`,

[image]

I have tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work

```
public class test
{
    private Min2Max range;

    [Category("Product")]
    public Min2Max Range
    {
        get { return range; }
        set { range = value; }
    }

    class Min2Max
    {
        private double min = 0.1;
        private double max = 99.9;

        public double Min
        {
            get { return min; }
            set { min = value; }
        }

        public double Max
        {
            get { return max; }
            set { max = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

any suggestions or help would be much appreciated, many thanks..:)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241887/property-grid-on-composite-objects?rq=1

Comment: I don't think so, I'm using nested class where as the other one uses two different classes.

Comment: You can't. The concept of "sub category" just doesn't exist in the property grid.

Comment: @Simon, Thanks I understand that, is there any way around to achieve this?

Comment: Nope. The .NET property grid not extensible like that.

Answer (score 1):

What you show in red in not a kind of subcategory but a property that has other child properties. The problem is that your `Min2Max` class and Range property are private, so the grid won't map them. If you fix this you will also need to attach to one of them a `TypeConverter` that "shows" the properties. At the very least, `ExpandableObjectConverter` can do it. If you need to enable editing the Range by itself (not its sub-properties), then your converter will have to take care of that too.

If you are more after a true subcategory, then Simon is right. It's not possible with the stock Microsoft PropertyGrid and you will have to rely on a 3rd party PropertyGrid.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you and just edited to `Public`, but I do not have any experience with `TypeConverter`, let me try.!